# spectral division

Tags: fft, phase, ifft

Sorry if this is elementary. If I add a small sinusoidal signal to my data and then take FFT of both my original and the modified one and then inverse FFT the division of the two, I should then be left with the sinusoid. But when I do the above, I get a shift in my output, as if the phase is lost. What am I doing wrong ? thanks.

FS = 500;

MODIFIED=fft(inp(512:1023)+sinus); %inp = data + tapered sinsus

INP=fft(inp);

out=ifft(MODIFIED./(INP+eps))/FS;

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you performing division? That's just an incorrect assumption. Since the DFT is a linear operation, if you add the sinusoid before the DFT, then if you wanted to cancel it out in the frequency domain, you would *subtract* the DFT of the sinusoid. Still not a very practical approach, but it would work for your example. There are very few cases where you would want to divide spectra; one problem is that if the denominator spectra has any nulls in it, your result ends up as infinite, which is unlikely to be desirable.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I don't know what I was thinking! I guess I had a lapse of reason and mixed up addition and convolution.